# Angular: Dynamic creation of components in HTML doesn't work

Tags: html, css, angular, typescript

I am able to dynamically create components:

```
import { Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterComponent } from '../filter/filter.component';

export enum FilterType {
  DateRangeFilter, SensorSelectFilter
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-collection',
  templateUrl: './filter-collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-collection.component.css']
})
export class FilterCollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  filters: Array<ComponentRef<FilterComponent>> = [];

  @ViewChild("messagecontainer", { read: ViewContainerRef }) entry!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  onAddDateRangeFilter() {
    const factory: ComponentFactory<FilterComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FilterComponent);
    const filter = this.entry.createComponent<FilterComponent>(factory);
    filter.instance.filter = FilterType.DateRangeFilter;
    this.filters.push(filter);
  }

  onAddSensorSelectFilter() {
    const factory: ComponentFactory<FilterComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FilterComponent);
    const filter = this.entry.createComponent<FilterComponent>(factory);
    filter.instance.filter = FilterType.SensorSelectFilter;
    this.filters.push(filter);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

while `FilterComponent` looks like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter',
  templateUrl: './filter.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter.component.css']
})
export class FilterComponent {

  @Input() filter!: FilterType;

  _FilterType = FilterType;

  range = new FormGroup({
    start: new FormControl(),
    end: new FormControl()
  });

  constructor() {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```

with this HTML:

```
<div *ngIf="filter === _FilterType.SensorSelectFilter">
<mat-form-field class="sensorFilter" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Cars</mat-label>
    <select matNativeControl required>
        <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
        <option value="saab">Saab</option>
        <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
        <option value="audi">Audi</option>
    </select>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
<div *ngIf="filter === _FilterType.DateRangeFilter">
<mat-form-field class="dateFilter" appearance="fill">
    <mat-label>Enter a date range to filter data</mat-label>
    <mat-date-range-input [formGroup]="range" [rangePicker]="picker">
        <input matStartDate formControlName="start" placeholder="Start date">
        <input matEndDate formControlName="end" placeholder="End date">
    </mat-date-range-input>
    <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
    <mat-date-range-picker #picker></mat-date-range-picker>

    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.start.hasError('matStartDateInvalid')">Invalid start date</mat-error>
    <mat-error *ngIf="range.controls.end.hasError('matEndDateInvalid')">Invalid end date</mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
</div>
```

However, I am not sure how to instantiate those components into HTML, I tried it like this in `FilterCollectionComponent.html`:

```
<div *ngFor="let filter of filters">
    <app-filter [filter]="filter.instance.filter"></app-filter>
</div>
```

But this doesn't work.

Any ideas why? Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: A bit vague what you are asking here. You are creating components programmatically and attaching them to a viewChild named messagecontainer already..? There is no further HTML involved if you are creating them like this. What do you actually need or what are your trying to resolve? Or are you just experimenting?

Comment: I would like to dynamically create `FilterComponent` based on which button was clicked ( either `onAddDateRangeFilter` or `onAddSensorSelectFilter` ). I don't understand at the moment how I can add these created components to the HTML. I am storing them inside an `Array<ComponentRef<FilterComponent>>` but I don't know if that's the right choice. I tried it with the last snipped of my post (`ngFor=...`) but that didn't work. @MikeOne

Comment: If you want to do it in the template, you do not need to programmatically create them.. Angular will do that for you..

Comment: How?? But `FilterComponent` changes its HTML representation based on `filter`-value @MikeOne

Comment: I’m trying to understand what you want to establish here. Programmatically creating component is quite a niche and advanced subject. You almost never need it (expect if for example you want to lazy load that component). However, combining programmatically created components with “now I want to show them in the template using a loop” - doesn’t make sense. You can simply create the loop for your component and pass the value you need te determine what your component does as an input (as you already seem to do anyway). For that, you don’t need to create those components like you do know..

Comment: Thank you, I solved it thanks to this example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-lusfbj?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Answer (score 0):

`filter-collection.component.html`:

```
<div #dynamicFilters></div>
```

`filter-collection.component.ts`

```
import { Component, ComponentFactory, ComponentFactoryResolver, ComponentRef, OnInit, ViewChild, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { FilterComponent } from '../filter/filter.component';

export enum FilterType {
  DateRangeFilter, SensorSelectFilter
}

@Component({
  selector: 'app-filter-collection',
  templateUrl: './filter-collection.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./filter-collection.component.css']
})
export class FilterCollectionComponent implements OnInit {

  filters : Array<ComponentRef<FilterComponent>> = [];

  @ViewChild('dynamicFilters', { read: ViewContainerRef }) dynamicInsert!: ViewContainerRef;

  constructor(private resolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) { }

  onAddDateRangeFilter() {
    const factory: ComponentFactory<FilterComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FilterComponent);
    const filter = this.dynamicInsert.createComponent<FilterComponent>(factory);
    filter.instance.filter = FilterType.DateRangeFilter;
    this.filters.push(filter);
  }

  onAddSensorSelectFilter() {
    const factory: ComponentFactory<FilterComponent> = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(FilterComponent);
    const filter = this.dynamicInsert.createComponent<FilterComponent>(factory);
    filter.instance.filter = FilterType.SensorSelectFilter;
    this.filters.push(filter);
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {

  }

}
```